# i wanted to ask about this error please Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot destructure property `data` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

so first this I use this in authentication im using redux and each time I try to fill the email and password forms and click sign in it give me this error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot destructure property `data` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

this is my code :

```
import {AUTH_ATTEMPTING, AUTH_SUCCESS, AUTH_FAILED } from'./types';
import axios from 'axios';

const token_name= 'vendo_app_token';
export const login = (request_data) =>{
    return async dispatch =>{
        dispatch ({type: AUTH_ATTEMPTING})
        try{
            const {data: {token}} = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/V1/login', request_data);
            dispatch(success(token) );
        }catch(e){
            const {response: {data}} = e;
            dispatch(error(data.error));                                  
        }
    };
};
```

and this is the path I use to connect into the home page

```
if(isAuth===true){
    this.props.history.push('/register');
}
```

Comment: What does the API call return?

Comment: Have you checked that axios returns correct data?

Comment: @elvira.genkel yes he returns actually everything is working even the token part is working also but the only problem is when i click sign in it give that error about data

Answer (score 0):

The only place where you are destructuring `data` is in the error handler, where you are trying to destructure to ultimately get `e.response.data`.  The error message you are getting indicates that the error that was thrown does not have a `response` property.

Try:

```
} catch(e) {
  if ( ! e.response ) {
    console.error( 'Error without response:', e );
  } else {
    const { response : { data } } = e;
    dispatch( error( data.error ) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

heyy jason well i got another error let me show you

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

```
36 |    );
  37 |    }
  38 |    if(isAuth){
> 39 |      this.props.history.push('/');
     | ^  40 |    }
  41 |  }
  42 |
```

and this error also :

```
  12 |              console.error( 'Error without response:', e );
  13 |            } else {
  14 |              const { response : { data } } = e;
> 15 |              dispatch( error( data.error ) );
     | ^  16 |            }
  17 |          }
  18 |
```